# FiPy Solving Couple PDEs Results in IndexError

Tags: python, pde, fipy

I am new to FiPy and am trying to solve a pair of coupled PDEs describing adsorption of a material to an adsorbent packed in a cylinder. The material is flowing through the cylinder and its concentration is in either of 2 phases: a mobile phase or a stationary phase. I took the mesh for the mobile phase to be a 1D grid along the long axis pf the cylinder. I took the mesh for stationary phase to be a cylindrical 1D grid for the cross-sectional area of the cylinder. The 2 phases are coupled and I'm trying to solve for the concentration of the material in the mobile phase over time.

```
import numpy as np
import fipy as fp

# meshes and variables
nx = 50.
dx = 1.

# mobile phase
mesh_m = fp.Grid1D(nx=nx, dx=dx)
cm = fp.CellVariable(name="Concentration mobile", mesh=mesh_m, value=0.)

# stationary phase
mesh_s = fp.CylindricalGrid1D(nr=50, dr=dx)
cs = fp.CellVariable(name="Concentration stationary", mesh=mesh_s, value=0.)

# phase equations 
# mobile
eqCm = fp.TransientTerm(coeff = 0.5, var = cm) \
    == fp.ExplicitDiffusionTerm(coeff = 0.03, var = cm) \
    - fp.PowerLawConvectionTerm((1,), var = cm) \
    - fp.ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff= 3 * (cm - cs), var = cm)  

# stationary
eqCs = fp.TransientTerm(coeff = 0.4, var = cs) \
    == fp.ExplicitDiffusionTerm(coeff = 0.2, var = cs) 
   
# boundary conditions 
# mobile
cm_Left = 1.
cm_Right = 0.
cm_gradValueLeft = 30 * (cm_Left - 1)
cm_gradValueRight = 0.

cm.constrain(cm_Left, mesh_m.facesLeft)

cm.faceGrad.constrain(cm_gradValueLeft, mesh_m.facesLeft)
cm.faceGrad.constrain(cm_gradValueRight, mesh_m.facesRight)

# stationary
cs_Left = 0.
cs_Right = 1.
cs_gradValueLeft = 0.
cs_gradValueRight = 0.01 * (cm - cs)

cs.constrain(cs_Right, mesh_s.facesRight)

cs.faceGrad.constrain(cs_gradValueLeft, mesh_s.facesLeft)
cs.faceGrad.constrain(cs_gradValueRight, mesh_s.facesRight)

# **************** setup system and solve *********************************
eqn = eqCm and eqCs

T = 100
timeStep = 0.5
steps = int(T/timeStep)
viewer = fp.Viewer(vars=(cm, cs), datamin=0., datamax=4)

for step in range(steps):
    eqn.solve(var=cm, dt=timeStep)
    print(cm)
    viewer.plot()
```

I keep running into the following error during the `eqn.solve(var=cm, dt=timeStep)` command: `IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 50 but corresponding boolean dimension is 51`. Is there something wrong with the way the cell variables or the equations are set up? Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very likely because `cm` and `cs` have 50 cells, leading to `cs_gradValueRight` having 50 cells. `mesh_s.facesRight` accesses 51 faces, though, so `cs.faceGrad.constrain(cs_gradValueRight, mesh_s.facesRight)` doesn't know what to do. To get rid of this error, you could write:

```py
cs.faceGrad.constrain(cs_gradValueRight.faceValue, where=mesh_s.facesRight)
```

You're still going to have problems, though:

- FiPy cannot couple equations between different meshes. In general, meshes can be concatenated, but I seriously doubt that a `Grid1D` can be concatenated to a `CylindricalGrid1D`. I'm pretty confident that it will lose the cylindrical geometry.
- FiPy couples equations with "`&`", not "`and`".

If I understand what you're trying to do, I think you will have much better luck solving a single concentration field on a `CylindricalGrid2D` and changing the properties of the medium between the mobile region and the stationary region.

Not a problem, but not not ideal: Use `DiffusionTerm` rather than `ExplicitDiffusionTerm`. It will solve much more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks @jeguyer! If `mesh_s.facesRight` accesses 51 faces, does `mesh_m.facesLeft` or `mesh_m.facesRight` also access 51 faces? Or is this extra face only occur with cylindrical grids? I tried adding the `faceValue` attribute to other `faceGrad.constrain` commands in my code just to see what would happen, but I get errors saying these do not have that attribute. I'm curious as to why this only works for `mesh_s.facesRight`. If there is documentation on this, would you be able to point me to that?

Comment: A 1D mesh with 50 cells will have 51 faces bounding those cells. That's true for both Cartesian and cylindrical meshes. Any `CellVariable` should have a `.faceValue` attribute. My original answer had a typo; `cs_gradValueRight` takes a `.faceValue`, not `mesh_s.facesRight` (or `mesh_m.facesRight`).